# GitHub create repository via curl "Problem parsing JSON"

Tags: windows, github-api

I want to create a new GitHub repository via curl but I always get the error: "Problems parsing JSON"

`curl -u "username:token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"test","private":true}'`

Error:

```
{
    "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

But the error only occurs when I'm using windows 10. I tried to execute the exact same command on my linux os and there everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out my self, the problem is the os.
On windows I have to replace the single quotes ' after -d and at the end with double quotes " and I have to use the backslash for the double quotes.
The working command looks like:

```
curl -u "username:token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"test\",\"private\":true}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows as well. I have the same error and wasn't able to get it working using your solution. With a little tweak, I got it working.

I surrounded the payload with single quotes and escaped the double quotes in the json payload.

```
curl -u "username:token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{\"name\":\"test\",\"private\":true}'
```